# Adding a string to iteslf in an $.each

Tags: jquery, json

I'm parsing a JSON array (called dataTablePath with each inside the array called path) with jQuery using $.each (nested inside another $.each) and need to have the data append to itself i.e.:

JSON:

```
{
    "dataTablePath": [
        {"path": "insurance"},
        {"path": "retirement"},
        {"path": "life"}
    ]
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('insuranceReport.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.insuranceReport, function(i, f) {
         $.each(f.dataTablePath, function(i, g) {
         urlDataFile = "dataTablePath" + i + "=" + g.path + "&";
            window.dataFile = urlDataFile + urlDataFile;
         });
     });
});
```

Hopefully you can understand what I'm loking to do.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the final string should be "dataTablePath0=insurance&dataTablePath1=retirement&dataTablePath2=life"?

Comment: can you show what the result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Errors:

1. Line 1: `$.getJSON('insuranceReport.json', function(data) {` instead of `$.getJSON('insuranceReport.json, function(data) {`
2. Use `window.dataFile += urlDataFile;` to append to `global var dataFile` instead of `window.dataFile = urlDataFile`

and i am assuming that `data.insuranceReport` gives the JSON which you have mentioned in the Original Post.

Comment: Is there some reason why my output is: "undefineddataTablePath0=auto insurance&dataTablePath1=auto insurance 2&dataTablePath2=auto insurance 3&" in the console?  I'm getting undefined beforre the first dataTablePath.  But worked other than that.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable at the very top. do `var dataFile = "";` and use `.replace(/&\s*$/, "");` to remove the last &

Comment: Thanks.  I actually need the last "&" i have another url variable I'm adding to this string.